# Can I make a bot that generates three non-repeating phrases from a list?

Tags: javascript, bots

I've been trying to teach myself Discord bots but I'm a noob so please bear with me.  First off I want to say that I really did hunt through this site to find this but everything I came up with seems to only work for numbers, not words ...

I am trying to make a bot give three responses from a list without any chance of repetition.  I understand that by preventing an item from repeating, the generated response is no longer "random."  This is the workaround I came up with for now:

```js
client.on('message', message => {
        const list1 = [
           'example A', 'example B'
        ]
        const list2 = [
           'example C', 'example D'
        ]
        const list3 = [
           'example E', 'example F'
        ]
        if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}fmk`)) {
           message.channel.send(`**redacted, Marry, Kill:**\n\n${list1[Math.floor(Math.random() * list1.length)]}\n${list2[Math.floor(Math.random() * list2.length)]}\n${list3[Math.floor(Math.random() * list3.length)]}`);
        }
});
```

Obviously you can see the problem with this.  It prevents a response like `example A, example A, example A,` but it also makes it impossible to get a combination like `example A, example B, example C`.

Is there a way that I could have one list like example A through example F and still get three non-repeating results from it?

I hope this makes sense.  Thanks :)

Comment: I don't think this is a discord.js related question.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `Fisher-Yates Shuffle` to move 3 values around randomly:

```js
function shuffle(array) {
    var i = array.length,
        j = 0,
        temp;

    while (i--) {

        j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i+1));

        // swap randomly chosen element with current element
        temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;

    }

    return array;
}

var ranStrings = shuffle(["Example A", "Example B", "Example C"]); //calling the func
```

Note: this function not only shuffles the array, but only allowed unique values to be output

**EDIT:** As mentioned above, this isn't really a Discord.js question, although it is related to a bot, it is more asking about `Javascript`, and it would be more suited there.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I fixed the tag.  I realized last night that I get confused because I threw myself into bot stuff first but I should probably step back and learn Javascript.  Thanks for being helpful :)

Comment: no problem at all, does my code work though?

Comment: Not gonna lie, I am currently trying to figure out where I'm supposed to plug it in to make sense with the `message.channel.send()` part   Still pretty new to all this ...

Comment: all you would do is something like this:
`message.channel.send(shuffle(["put the statements here", "example 2", "example 3"]));`

shuffle is a function, it will simply swap the input elements around

Comment: I might have worded my question poorly, I'm not sure where to tell it that I only want three things.  I'm actually trying to have it pick three things out of a list of 94 with no chance of repeating any of those 94 things.  Does that make sense?

Comment: just set a random function, and pick 3 random indexes between 0 and 94, then shuffle them

Answer (score 0):

I never got back to this to say that I just ended up using Lodash and it worked great :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).